# tkinter GUI not running in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

So i have a simple chat program using python sockets and a tkinter GUI and i am using threading to run the GUI in one thread and the receive code in the other thread, When i run it the GUI flashes open then closes. How would i have it receive the messages while keeping the GUI open i am using python 3.7.9

```
import socket
import select
import errno
import sys
import threading

HEIGHT = 400
WIDTH = 500

HEADER_LENGTH = 10
IP = "#your ip address" 
PORT = 1234

text = ""

def send_message(message):
    message = message
  
    #message = input(f"[{my_username}]")

    if message:
        message = message.encode("utf-8")
        message_header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")
        client_socket.send(message_header + message)

def msgr():

    my_username = input("Username: ")
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
    client_socket.setblocking(False)

    username = my_username.encode("utf-8")
    username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("UTF-8")
    client_socket.send(username_header + username)


    while True:
        
        try:
            while True:
                username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
                if not len(username_header):
                    print("closed connection")
                    sys.exit()
                username_length = int(username_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
                username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode("utf-8")

                message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
                message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
                message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode("utf-8")

                print(f"{username} >{message}")
                
                    
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                print("Reading error",str(e))
                sys.exit()
            continue

        except Exception as e:
            print("genaral error", str(e))
            sys.exit()
def GUI():
    root = tk.Tk()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT,width=WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()

    frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#DCDCDC", bd=5)
    frame.place(relx=.0,rely=.0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

    message_list = tk.Label(root, justify="left",anchor="nw",text=text) 
    message_list.place(relx=.22,rely=.13, relwidth=.55,relheight=.7)

    message_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
    message_entry.place(relx=.22,rely=.9, relwidth=.50)

    send = tk.Button(frame, text="Send", command=lambda: send_message(message_entry.get()))
    send.place(relx=.77,rely=.91)

    #root.after(5000, msgr)
    root.mainloop()

    


t1 = threading.Thread(target=GUI)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=msgr)
t2.start()
t1.start()
```

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading.

Comment: you can still use tkinter and multithreading @martineau

Comment: @coderoftheday: That's not what I said.

Comment: my mistake @martineau

Comment: @coderoftheday: Possibly better way to have stated it: Only one thread can access `tkinter` in a multithreaded application.

Comment: don't you mean you cant run tkinter in a thread?, since its possible to pack widgets from another thread in tkinter main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=GUI)
```

to

```
GUI()
```

and delete

```
t1.start()
```

Tkinter runs in the mainthread, then you can create threads which run it their own threads in this case `t2`

but also

```
client_socket
```

isn't defined

Have you also imported tkinter?

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Comment: It works thanks and yes i did import tkinter i just forgot to put it on